# remove UITableViewCell Custom

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

Is there a way to remove UTableCell? 
Basically I have two `UIButtons` and two Custom `UITableCell` 
 
and depending on what button is pressed I want to display the Custom `UITableCell`

 Once the `UIViewController` is loaded, it displays one of the Custom `UITableCell`. 
What I want to do is when the second `UIButton` is pressed to remove the first `UITableCell` and display the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (cell == nil) {

    //If button 1 was clicked

        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier1";
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell1" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableViewTblCell1; //tableViewCell1 is the object of TableViewCell1
        self.tableViewTblCell1= nil;

    //Else If button 2 was clicked
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier2";
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell2" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableViewTblCell2; //tableViewCell2 is the object of TableViewCell2
        self.tableViewTblCell2= nil;
}
```

**and do whatever you want to do with cell **

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your custom cell based on your button click for that you need to remember which button is clicked.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if([aVarible isEqualToString:@"firstButton"])
    {
      //create your first custom cell
    }
    else if ([aVarible isEqualToString:@"secondButton"])
    {
       //create your second custom cell
    }
 }
```

in your button click event

```
- (IBAction) firstBtnClick
{
   aVarible = @"firstButton"
   [yourTable reloadData]
}

- (IBAction) secondBtnClick
{
   aVarible = @"secondButton"
   [yourTable reloadData]
}
```

hope it gives to idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update your data source, then call `-reloadData` on the table view. If you want to use animation, you can also use `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.